# How do I locate a Google SpreadSheet ID?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#parameter_and_return_types

When using the Google Execution Api for Java, the ID of the spreadsheet isn't very easy to understand. Here is the code snippet:

```
// Initialize parameters for that function.
String sheetId = "<ENTER_ID_OF_SPREADSHEET_TO_EXAMINE_HERE>";
List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
params.add(sheetId);
```

Any Ideas on how to locate this. I run the Sheets api to return the id of a SpreadSheet but it returns a link, and when I use the https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/*STRING* or just the *STRING* itself I still get:
"code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Found this deep inside the Apps Script API reference.

A spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL. For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is "abc1234567".

Comment: NVM, found right at top of docs: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Answer (score 48):

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

states that:

Every API method requires a spreadsheetId parameter which is used to identify which spreadsheet is to be accessed or altered. This ID is the value between the "/d/" and the "/edit" in the URL of your spreadsheet. For example, consider the following URL that references a Google Sheets spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qpyC0XzvTcKT6EISywvqESX3A0MwQoFDE8p-Bll4hps/edit#gid=0
```

The ID of this spreadsheet is **1qpyC0XzvTcKT6EISywvqESX3A0MwQoFDE8p-Bll4hps**.

So I just pulled up my spreadsheet and looked at the URL to find my ID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So uh... how do you find this ID just using code?  It's pretty useless for automation if you have to manually open each spreadsheet and copy/paste an ID from the URL...

Comment: @Michael did you make any progress? I'm having the same problem. I can retrieve an id for a sheet using `currentSheet.getSheetId();` but it is a simple integer (0 for a one sheet App) but can't find anything equivalent to get the id of the SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but in my case I was creating  a sheet, so the BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest returns a BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse object, in the properties was the sheetId.   execute.getReplies().get(0).getAddSheet().getProperties().getSheetId()

Answer (score -5):

I just created a hyperlink to the sheets and then copied that hyperlink to a text file and the link line shows the GID.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TxNHS6vuse1is2Mw_hUs9wTDM6f095Y6pKLeltUfNzQ/edit#gid=1049871492

Then I created a pull down list in A52 and then made =IF() logic to go to the GIDs to go to those sheets.

=IF(A52="47QTCK18D0001",HYPERLINK("#gid=0","47QTCK18D0001"),IF(A52="47QTCK18D0002",HYPERLINK("#gid=1049871492","47QTCK18D0002") ....