# In NodeJS, how do you access the google-sheets ID from its URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm new at Node, and I'm trying to access a google spreadsheet by pasting the URL in 'new GoogleSpreadhseet(id). When I just paste the id it works, but if I try to paste the url and put the string through a parser that returns just the id, it gives an error.

Is this an issue with the google spreadsheet node_modules, or something in my own code?

Comment: it could be helpful, you can retrieve from url, it looks like has a pattern. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061433/how-to-do-i-locate-a-google-spreadsheet-id

Comment: To add to Juan's comment, this approach works for all files in Drive.