# Exporting data to another spreadsheet based on 2 checkbox criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and my friend told me to ask over here! For some context, I have multiple projects where we track each invoice our sub-contractors send. Each project has its own spreadsheet. The invoice tracking sheet looks like this:
[Sub-Contractor Tracker Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzXs0.png)
[image]

Once the **Billed?** checkbox is true, A12:D12 should populate another spreadsheet, (Sheet Y). The tricky part for me is that I'd like it to be removed from Sheet Y once the **Final Verification** checkbox is marked true. (So **Billed?** and **Final Verification** would both be marked true) I'm able to use SQL imports to linked sheets to get the data to Sheet Y if **Billed?** is true but the Final Verification second criteria is the main issue I'm running into.

I'm not too great at explaning things so please let me know if you need some more clarification.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: Is Invoice Number Unique?

Comment: What does SheetY look like?

Answer (score 0):

**RECOMMENDATION:**

You can check this option below by using a combination of [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275), [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340), [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304), [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364), [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140) & [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) functions and then place it on cell `A1` of the **Sheet Y** spreadsheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(importRange("GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID", "SHEET_NAME!K12:K") = false, TRIM(QUERY(importRange("GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID", "SHEET_NAME!A12:K"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col9 = TRUE")),""),""))
```

Just replace the `GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID` with your actual **Sub-Contractor Tracker** spreadsheet ID. Click [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061433/how-to-do-i-locate-a-google-spreadsheet-id?answertab=votes#tab-top) if you do not know where to locate the Sheets ID. And lastly, replace `SHEET_NAME` with the actual sheet name on your **Sub-Contractor Tracker** spreadsheet.

**NOTE:**

I'm unable to replicate what you've done here, "***I'm able to use SQL imports to linked sheets to get the data to Sheet Y if Billed? is true***", so I've used `QUERY(importRange("GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID", "SHEET_NAME!A12:K"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col9 = TRUE")` function on my testing to populate 'Sheet Y' if **Col9** or **Billed?** has a `true` value.

**SAMPLE**

**Sub-Contractor Tracker** spreadsheet w/ data on 'Sub-Contractor Tracker' sheet:

[image]

Spreadsheet **Sheet Y** with the combination of functions added on cell `A1`:

[image]

**Example Scenario:**

If Invoice # **1** gets verified:

[image]

Invoice # **1** gets removed on the on spreadsheet **Sheet Y**:

[image]