# html code for sankey diagram from github return blank window

Tags: html, google-sheets

[Link to GitHub](https://gist.github.com/njoerd114/839b9a5298843ea4cf9fd241e39ebbf6)

I am receiving a blank white window running. Would someone be able to provide input on what needs to be entered in lines 10 and 12 of code.gs?

I attempted to enter the ID of the tab where the data is located on for line 10 and had the tab number of where I want the graph to appear but still having issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines 10 and 12 of code.gs`

- Line 10 - this is the ID of your spreadsheet.

  - Open you spreadsheet and look at the URL. The ID consists of letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores. There's a very good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49042689/1330560) that shows exactly how to find the id.
  - insert the ID **between** the double quotation marks  on line 10
  - **BEFORE** `var ssID = "",`
  - **AFTER** `var ssID = "1wjyxtbWo06IOTF1ilTyQ3tLUidlEiEsOuXJGcbFXcPY",` (this is MY id, you should type in your own.
  - do **NOT** delete the comma at the end of Line 10
- Line 12:

  - if the sheet with your Sankey data is the first (or only) sheet in the spreadsheet, then do nothing
  - if the sheet with your Sankey data is **NOT** the first (or only) sheet in the spreadsheet, then move it so that it the first sheet in the list of sheets

Comment: Thank you so much, it turns out I was putting the wrong values and an AD block was running that prevented the chart from loading.